# ASP.NET MVC - Implicit Form Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, html-helper

I have a form which is part of a partial view and I need to submit it to a different location based on the context of the view containing the form. I can't use Html.BeginForm because the form has a multipart/form-data enctype so having the action filled in automatically is out the door.

Is there a simple variable I can call to fill in the current controller/action as my form action? I see that ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"], ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] will return those values, but is there a better accessor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way `HtmlHelper.BeginForm()` fills the action and controller *automatically* is by using `Request.RawUrl`. So you could just write:

```
<form action="<%= Request.RawUrl %>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ....
</form>
```

Comment: Awesome Sauce. This did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did

first full view:

```
 <% using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Admin",FormMethod.Post, 
              new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })){%>
            <% Html.RenderPartial("MerchandiseEditDetail", Model); %>
   <%}%>>
```

second full view:

```
 <% using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Admin",FormMethod.Post, 
       new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })){%>
    <% Html.RenderPartial("MerchandiseEditDetail", Model); %>
<%}%>
```

I am still looking for a better solution, but this partially solve my problem for now.